# Updating only Last row of datatable to all index of List<T>. Need to convert datatable to List

Tags: vb.net

```
  Dim dt As DataTable = catheter.FetchCatheter()
    Dim ct As New EntityObjects.CatheterTypeBO
    Dim cList As New List(Of EntityObjects.CatheterTypeBO)
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        ct.ID = dt.Rows(i)("ID")
        ct.Type = dt.Rows(i)("CTYPE")
        ct.Active = dt.Rows(i)("ACTIVE").ToString()
        cList.Add(ct)
    Next
```

updating all index of cList by last row of dt. Need to convert datatable to List

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `AsEnumerable` then `Last()` like:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = catheter.FetchCatheter()
Dim ct As New EntityObjects.CatheterTypeBO
Dim cList As New List(Of EntityObjects.CatheterTypeBO)
Dim dr as DataRow = dt.AsEnumerable().Last()

ct.ID = dr("ID")
ct.Type = dr("CTYPE")
ct.Active = dr("ACTIVE").ToString()
cList.Add(ct)
```

Comment: Now binding only of List<T>. Need to convert all rows of datatable to List<T>

Comment: I thought you say "only last row" :-) How about Dim ie as IENumerable(Of EntityObjects.CatheterTypeBO) = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList(Of EntityObjects.CatheterTypeBO)? would it work?

Comment: Not working...because "Extension method ToList not a generic method"